# Scroll behaviour of Tablayout with ActionBar is not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement behaviour like whatsApp.

**Expected Behaviour :**
When user scrolles the list `Tablayout` scrolls up with action bar.

`ActionBar` hides and insted `Tablayout` takes it's place.

**What's happening :**
Everything is working good with `ActionBar` and `Tablayout` but when scrolled up place of `Tablayout` is taken by white space.

[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOwrB.jpg),  [ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiEua.jpg)

and I am trying to remove that white space but couldn't.

Below is my `Activity` and `Fragment` code

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private LockableViewPager viewPager;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private MaterialSearchView searchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WhatsApp");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, -tabLayout.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            tabLayout.setAnimation(animate);
            viewPager.setSwipeAble(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, tabLayout.getHeight());
            tabLayout.setAnimation(animate);
            viewPager.setSwipeAble(true);
        }
    });

}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "CHATS");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "STATUS");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "CALLS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
        searchView.closeSearch();
        viewPager.setSwipeAble(true);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="6dp">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3" />

</FrameLayout>


<com.example.fragmentcontroller.view_pager.LockableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`Tab1Fragment.java`

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


private float mToolbarHeight;

public Tab1Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private View view;
private MaterialSearchView searchView;
private ArrayList<ModelD> modelDArrayList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FrameLayout toolbarContainer;
private TabLayout tabs;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    searchView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    toolbarContainer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_container);
    tabs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mToolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(getContext());
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.equals("")) {
                bindList(modelDArrayList);
            } else {
                ArrayList<ModelD> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < modelDArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if 
(modelDArrayList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains((newText).toLowerCase())) {
                        arrayList.add(modelDArrayList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                bindList(arrayList);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    modelDArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    bindList(modelDArrayList);
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener(getContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            if (!searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
                hideViews();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoved(int distance) {
            if (!searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
                toolbarContainer.setTranslationY(-distance);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            showViews();
        }
    });

}

private void hideViews() {
    toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new 
 AccelerateInterpolator(2));
//        tabs.animate().translationY(-mToolbarHeight).setInterpolator(new 
AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}

private void showViews() {
    toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
//         tabs.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}

private void bindList(ArrayList<ModelD> arrayList) {
    if (arrayList.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            ModelD modelD = new ModelD();
            modelD.setName("Name " + i);
            arrayList.add(modelD);
        }
    }
    DAdapter adapter = new DAdapter(getContext(), arrayList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}

}
```

`tab1_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view_pager.fragments.Tab1Fragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please use  AppBarLayout in your xml file before Toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CoordinatorLayout`

The `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`, `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` that you are using only work in CoordinatorLayout.

---

A proper implementation will somewhat look like below.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <com.example.fragmentcontroller.view_pager.LockableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

check this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/12858/android-tablayout-appbarlayout), if you want a more detailed explanation.